# Android Studio have error in emulator design not work

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I do this on the design side as you see but look at what appears in the emulator. How I can fix this error?

[image]

Comment: You are missing constraints on the widgets ... I recommend you to please go through some basics videos of Constraints Layout ...

Comment: If you read the error message you would know `This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints`. Click on this white circle on `EditText` and `Button` and connect it to the device edge in the designer.

Comment: thank you... it's solved now

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the proper constraints of button or edit text

Please check below code and Screen shot

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Please Type YTour Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:text="Send Now"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" />
```

[image]